# Searching for a specific object in an ArrayList Java

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I am trying to find a specific object based on user input. The user is to enter a name and a gender and then the program is supposed to search an ArrayList and see if there is a name and gender that matches. The object in the ArrayList has 3 instance variables, but the program only searches for 2. How can I search for only a select few characteristics in an ArrayList?

In my program I have:

```
int nameListLength = nameList.size();
   .
   .
   .

boolean done = false;
while (!done) {
   System.out.println ("Please enter a name:");
   String searchName = input.nextLine();
   if (searchName.equals("DONE")) {
      done = true;
   } else {
      System.out.println ("Please enter a gender:");
      String searchGender = input.nextLine();
      // Search the ArrayList.
      for (int i = 0; i < nameListLength; i++) {
         // See if the gender is in the ArrayList
         if (searchGender.equals(nameList.get(i).getGender())) {
            // See if the name matches the gender in the ArrayList
            if (searchName.equals(nameList.get(i).getName())) {
               System.out.println ("Match found");
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Where nameList is the name of the ArrayList, getName() is the name of the method that returns the name stored in the object, and getGender() is the name of the method that returns the gender stored in the object. I put in debug statements to determine that the ArrayList is stoing the information correctly, I'm just having problems figuring out how to search for what I am looking for. I know there is a contains(Object o) method, but I am not sure if I can implement that here since I only need to match 2 characteristics of the object even though the object contains 3 pieces of data.

Comment: The code you posted looks OK, it does what you describe. What problem are you having with it exactly?

Comment: No, it's not working which is why I am asking if there is a way to search for only two of the three parts. e.x. let's say an object contains the following: 'name = Fred', 'gender = "M"', and 'frequency = 184' so that object is stored in the ArrayList, but we don't know it (it was read in from a text file). The user is prompt info regarding the Name and Gender. Based on what the user types, the program should search the arraylist to see if the name is in the list for the specified gender. So I want to search for name and gender, but have no use for frequency. How can I search for just those 2?

Comment: When I run the program, the program prompts me for a name, so I type a name I see on the list to test it. Then it prompts me for a gender, so I type the corresponding gender. It should say "Match Found" but instead it just goes on and prompts me for another name.

Comment: Then the list probably contains something else than what you think it contains. Run the program in a debugger, step through it, see what happens. Or add `System.out.println(...)` statements so that you can follow what exactly is happening.

Comment: I did, I put some debug statements to print out the parts of multiple different elements to see if they were being stored correctly and they were.

Comment: Then look again, very carefully. Maybe names have trailing spaces or newline characters, or the case is different ("Fred" vs "fred" or "M" vs "m", etc.).

Comment: Ah! I found the problem! You were right! I collected the frequency of the name, the gender, but when I collected the name I put file.nextLine() which grabbed an extra token. I changed that to file.next() and then it gave me what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Generally your code looks ok even if it is a bit untidy. You claim that it does not work, but I cannot see the obvious bug so I would double check the input list and the search terms (like case specificity for example).

Do not override the equal just to be able to use contains as it would imply that you always are going to compare your object just by those two properties.

You may consisder using the new Stream API which has few methods that does exactly what you are looking for:

```
List<Yourtype> found = list.stream().filter(u -> u.getName().equals(searchName) && u.getGender().equals(searchGender)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

check if there is a matching element

```
boolean isMath = list.stream().anyMatch(u -> u.getName().equals(searchName) && u.getGender().equals(searchGender));
```

take first matching:

```
Yourtype match = list.stream().findFirst(u -> u.getName().equals(searchName) && u.getGender().equals(searchGender)).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the List.**contains** method,you will need to implement the **equals()** method on the object that contains the data, so it can determine if the object is truly equal to another object.

In your instance you will simply implement that 2 out of 3 pieces of data needs to be equal so then the equals() method can return true.

Comment: But I think this is not the way to go since he's comparing only 2 out of 3 pieces in class

Comment: Then compare only 2 out of 3 in your class in the equals method. For more information read on how to implement the equals() method http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question, you want to fetch the matching Object based on the input.

You already posted a viable solution. You only need to get the Object with nameList.get(i) where your System.out.println ("Match found") is.

You can also use for()-Loops to cycle through every item in the list, so you don't need to take the long way by using the lenght.

```
boolean done = false;
YourObject result;
while (!done) {
   System.out.println ("Please enter a name:");
   String searchName = input.nextLine();
   if (searchName.equals("DONE")) {
      done = true;
   } else {
      System.out.println ("Please enter a gender:");
      String searchGender = input.nextLine();
      // Search the ArrayList.
      for (YourObject item: nameList) {
         // See if the gender is in the ArrayList
         if (searchGender.equals(item.getGender())) {
            // See if the name matches the gender in the ArrayList
            if (searchName.equals(item.getName())) {
               result = item;
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

result would be your matching Object

Comment: Hey thanks for the code. I am actually not trying to fetch the object, what I want to do is search the array the for name and gender entered by the user, and if the program finds it, then print out a statement saying "Match found" or something. So, lets say in this text file there is a line that says "1848 M Fred" 1848 times the name was used, the gender, and the name itself. That information is stored in the ArrayList (since the text file is thousands of lines long, we don't know if it is in there or not) so that's why the user types a name and gender and we have to see if the name matches.

Comment: Are you sure you read the text file correctly wihtout any Whitespaces or new lines at the end? Maybe this is blocking the equals on the Strings

Comment: I found the error. The text file was reading correctly, the problem was that for one of the pieces I was using the .nextLine() method which grabbed an extra token. I changed that to the .next() method and it is working properly now :)

Answer (score 0):

`Collection.contains()` ultimately uses `equals()` and `hashCode()` of your Object (Name? - I'm calling it that in this post).  It would work **if** you wrote Name.equals() and Name.hashCode() to only use the two fields, not all three.  However, that is probably incorrect.  At some other time the third field would be important.  Unfortunately, in Java, you cannot "plug and play" different equals() methods.  At least, not at all easily.

However, you can use a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) along with the utilities in [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html).  For example, within your Name class, implement

```
public static final NAME_AND_GENDER_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<Name>() {
  // code goes here
}
```

Then, call (you might want to do this on a copy of nameList, as it will reorder it)

`Collections.sort(nameList, Name.NAME_AND_GENDER_COMPARATOR);`

Now, everything is sorted.  Then call

```
Name searchFor = new Name(theName, theGender);  // make a mock Name to search for
int index = Collections.binarySearch(nameList, searchFor, Name.NAME_AND_GENDER_COMPARATOR);
if (index >= 0)
   // found it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in your "Person" object @Override the equals method, then use contains() method from collection.

`@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    final Product other = (Product) obj;
    if (obj==null){
           return false;}
    else if(this.name.equals(other.name) && this.gender.equals(other.gender{
          return true;}
    else{
         return false;}
}`
```